# html special characters into outfile.txt

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I've got a database where for efficiency, i've put the data into the db in html encoded formats.

I do maintenance on the data, and then move it into production via an 'into outfile', so it ends up in a text file.

The special characters don't make it across cleanly, and it comes out as all messed up code.

Is there a way to maintain the format for the txt file? 
Or should I be using another format?

The 'outfile' , and 'import'I find very efficient for doing a bulk transfer.

If i can't use that, any suggestions on the best way to find special characters in mysql?
The only thing I've found seems to find fields that ONLY contain non-ascii characters

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE NOT columnToCheck REGEXP '[A-Za-z0-9]';
```

Comment: Can you include a sample of this "messed up code" and what you would have expected if it were "clean"?

Comment: I'm not sure how well this will come out, but I'll try. 
messed up code 
john O'conner is coming out
<pre>john OÃ¢â¬â¢conner</pre>
That's pretty bad...

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you're storing HTML encoded text in the database? As discussed in [episode 58 of the Stack Overflow podcast](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/podcast-58/), you should always try to store raw data at the highest level of precision possible.

Comment: Not much for podcasts, so I missed that. I searched a bunch on the web before, and the consensus seemed to be that if it was going to be returned in html encoding, why not store it as such. I may have been looking in the wrong places. 

I'm happy to change it, but can't seem to pull out the issue rows.